# Optimizing Android threads which are used to send network data

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, optimization

I am working with an app which uses two threads in order to read and send data to server. Each thread runs a while loop; a que holds a que of commands which are dequed to send to the server. This way I can line up a large number of commands which are dequed and sent to the server one by one.

The command sender is as such

```
 class writeThread extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
 {
    byte[] buffer;
    LittleEndianDataOutputStream outputStream;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        try
        {
            buffer = new byte[4096];
            outputStream = new LittleEndianDataOutputStream(dataHolder.connection.getOutputStream());

            try
            {
                dataHolder.flags latestFlag;
                while (true)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        latestFlag = dataHolder.sendFlags.remove();
                        ByteBuffer sendBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
                        sendBytes.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                        switch (latestFlag) 
                        {
                            case sendDataRequest:
                                sendBytes.putInt(20);
                                outputStream.write(sendBytes.array());
                                break;
                            case getSelectedData:
                                sendBytes.putInt(21);
                                sendBytes.put(dataHolder.latestSelected.getBytes());
                                outputStream.write(sendBytes.array());
                                break;
                            case disconnect:
                                sendBytes.putInt(254);
                                sendBytes.put(dataHolder.latestSelected.getBytes());
                                outputStream.write(sendBytes.array());
                                break;                                    

                        }


                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException ex){}
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {}

        }
        catch (Exception ex){};
        return null;

    }


}
```

The read loop looks as such

```
     while (inputStream.read() > -1)
```

As a result, the app ends up taking up 50% of processing power of the phone. Are there any suggestions on how to optimize socket listening and data sending?

Note: Yes I know I am using a try catch for the queue instead of and if statement to check if the queue not empty. I am sure that the error throwing is not helping the optimization but I don't think it would push the processor to 50%. Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: Lol I just realized I have a unused 4kb buffer sitting around. Must of been left over from previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you are basically doing a busy wait - if there is nothing to send, it immediate goes to the exception handler and tries again - thus taking up all the cpu on that core.

What you want instead is a way to wait until an event is available. I suggest that you create a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html), and use a Handler that is associated with that thread to handle writing to the data stream.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("blah");
handlerThread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {
    public boolean HandleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case sendDataRequest:
               ...
            case getSelectedData:
               ...
            case disconnect:
               ...
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would create messages with the appropriate id and data, and send them to the handler with [handler.sendMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessage%28android.os.Message%29)

Alternately (and perhaps more simply), if you made your dataHolder.sendFlags collection an ArrayBlockingQueue, rather than whatever it is currently (I'm guessing ArrayList or similar?), then, when you go to remove the next element with [ArrayBlockingQueue.take()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29), it will wait until something is available (*without* performing a busy wait that takes up all the available cpu time)

Comment: Is the public boolean HandleMessage(Message msg) part of the new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper())? There is a closing before the opening bracket. I haven't used Java for anything major since highschool, I'm a little dry on it so I might be miss understanding the initialization.

Comment: That is what is know as an anonymous class. This is simultaneously creating a new subclass of Handler, and a new instance of that subclass, that overrides Handler.HandleMessage. See, for example, http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Comment: Ah, interesting, I don't think I've seen that in Java. I am used to seeing that in ({}); or am I not understanding something?

Comment: I am a little bit confused. I am guessing that this is not part of the writeThread? I need to make sure that as soon as anything is pushed to the queue (which can be multiple things) it will dequeue everything in that Que as soon as items are available in the Queue. I looked through examples and I don't quite understand how this will make it an automated process...

Comment: The HandlerThread is meant to replace your existing writeThread. When you send the handler a message with sendMessage, HandleMessage will be called on the HandlerThread to handle that message. Multiple messages can be sent very close to each other - they will be queued up and will be handled in the order that they are sent.

Comment: Ok, I utilized the LinkedBlockingQue. That works really well to make the while loop wait. I would rather do it that way because it keeps me from having to bend over backwards to get that function called from other classes and scopes. Thank you very much! When there is nothing in the que, the cpu is at 0% usage.